# Control and Output Music Note

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, controls

I am writing a program so that to click a button and according to the time you have kept your mouse down the linked note is printed. My problem is that the first click works fine but when I hold on for the second time it doesn't update and it is driving me crazy. Any help will be much appreciated. Below find the following code I am using. Thanks

For the Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NoteShape
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int duration = 0;
        MusicNote mn;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            duration++;
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                duration = 0;
            }
        }

        private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
            duration = duration % 20;

            string bNoteShape = "";

            if (duration >= 12)
            {
                bNoteShape = "SemiBreve";
            }

            if ((duration >= 6) && (duration <= 11))
            {
                bNoteShape = "Minim";
            }

            if ((duration >= 3) && (duration <= 5))
            {
                bNoteShape = "Crotchet";
            }

            if ((duration >= 1) && (duration <= 2))
            {
                bNoteShape = "Quaver";
            }

            if (duration == 0)
            {
                bNoteShape = "SemiQuaver";
            }


            mn = new MusicNote(1, bNoteShape);
            MessageBox.Show(bNoteShape);
            this.Controls.Add(this.mn);

        }
    }
}
```

For the according class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace NoteShape
{
    class MusicNote: PictureBox
    {
        public string path = "ImagesName\\";
        public int pitch;
        public string noteShape;

        public MusicNote(int iPitch, string iNoteShape) : base()
        {
            pitch = iPitch;
            noteShape = iNoteShape;

            Location = new Point(150, 50);
            Size = new Size(40, 40);
            Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(path + noteShape + ".bmp");
            Image = bmp1;
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest to use Environment.TickCount instead of incrementing your own duration. Take the value in the mouseDown and take a new value in the mouseUp, do the difference and you have the duration in millisecond: see this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx

Comment: I can't because the professor only wants to use classes done in class that's why... but still the problem remains :/

Comment: What do you means by "classes done in class". Environnement.TickCount is part of the .NET framework and is available like any other class like Bitmap ou Point that you already are using in your project. Also, you should write the project specification in the question if you want help because we don't know them.

Comment: during lecture the class Environment.TickCount was not mentioned so I can't use it. The only things I need to use are simple coding like I mention in the question. Regards the project specification it says, using the above code perform a user MusicNote Component with a Note shape determined by user generated timer, duration, when the Button or Music Key is Presses. Thanks for all the help Jean..

Comment: What is the interval of your timer1?

Comment: the interval of timer1 is 100ms, it is showing the note but only 1 is showing per run. that is the problem...

Comment: Is there some reason that you are creating a new picturebox each time? Check the Z order for the new picture boxes to make sure that the newly created are not being placed under the original. Or simply reuse the same picture box.

Comment: the same PictureBox is supposedly being used..

Comment: @kurtborg92 Are you sure about that? Your code says differently. `new MusicNote(1, bNoteShape);` creates a new MusicNote which is your own derived PictureBox. Then you add it to the controls collection, `this.Controls.Add(this.mn);`

Comment: And you what do you suggest then?

Comment: @kurtborg92 Well I would suggest that you use a base picturebox control and then just change the Image property on your MouseUp event. If you _must_ use your own derived picturebox, then create it on startup and set the Image property in your MouseUp event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code "as is" in Visual Studio 2010 without any problem. The only thing I changed was that I comment the bitmap since I didn't had them but I choose the background color black to see it.

```
 //Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(path + noteShape + ".bmp");
 //Image = bmp1;
 BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Also, I put the timer1 with a 500 ms interval because I didn't know what was your interval.

I can do it over and over again and the message box pop with the right thing in it!
Can you try it again or maybe update your code because right now, there is no problem at all.

EDIT

You need to add this in your button1_MouseUp

```
this.Controls.Add(mn);
mn.BringToFront();
```

The picturebox was drawn behind the previous one.

Comment: the only problem is the image Jean. The message box is showing correctly but the control is only adding the first generated note.

Comment: This means that the black box will always show correctly because it outputs only a black box all the time.. if you try to move the black box meaning it outputs in a different location after the first run it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new note but are placing it at the same position every time.

You should either edit the existing/clicked note or position the new note.

Comment: So you should first detect what note you clicked and enter editmode or create a new note and position it. The editing of a not could be added to the MusicNote.Clicked events, that way you do not have to detect what note was clicked.